# Finding speed of train from just Mass and Latitude

Tags: classical-mechanics

So I am doing this textbook problem which states (I have changed some of the values just so I can get an understanding of what to do, I do not want the answer)

> While taking an eastbound train to work, a passenger of fixed mass finds that she weighs 200 N. On the way home she weighs herself again while the train is at full speed and finds she weighs 250 N. If she works 100 km from home, how long is her commute if she lives at $32^{\circ} S$? (You may assume that the average speed of the train is its full speed.)

and I was told as a hint in the text that to calculate mass:

> You can calculate this from the average (stationary) weight, and a constant value of g

My inital thought was to look at the centrifugal acceleration as I don't believe I can look at the coriolis force as I do not have the speed nor defelction of the train.

However when considering just the centrifual acceleration, I cannot grab the velocity as I do not have the timeframe over which this occurs.

I am truly stuck and I do not know if I am just missing something (like a concept or equation). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *When considering just the centrifual acceleration, I cannot grab the velocity as I do not have the timeframe over which this occurs.* What is the centripetal acceleration of something moving with speed $v$ in a circle of radius $R$?

Comment: It is $v^2 R$, the reason why I figured I couldn’t use this was because of the earths rotation, and that it wouldn’t be a perfect circle but rather an arc length of a circle.

Comment: No, it’s $v^2/R$. And instantaneous acceleration along a path has nothing to do with the entire path. It has to do with an infinitesimal segment of the path.

Comment: Ohhh ok, sorry the only thing that’s mentioned in my text about that is $v^2 R$ where v is the rotation of the earth, and R is the rotation axis. So for this to work, all I’d need to do is calculate the average mass, use the distance she travels as the radius and set that equal to the force she measures yes ?